# Scala - Extractor Objects confusion

Tags: scala, extractor

I am kind of confused about extractor and its using. I read Scala document and meet that one

```
object Twice {
  def apply(x: Int): Int = x * 2
  def unapply(z: Int): Option[Int] = if (z%2 == 0) Some(z/2) else None
}
object TwiceTest extends App {
  val x = Twice(21)  // x = 42
  x match { case Twice(n) => Console.println(n) } // prints 21
}`
```

As the above code print out, when we call `x match {case Twice(n) ...`, it means `Twice(n)` --> `Twice.unapply(n)` --> `Twice.unapply(42)` and get `Some(n/2)` --> `Some(42/2)` and plug result into `n` again, print out `21`

If I change "unapply" as follow:
`def unapply(z: Int): Option[Int] = if (z%2 == 0) Some(z - 2) else None`

What I get from the console is `40`

So, do I understand it right?

Comment: yes, what's the question?

Comment: So, it now change `n`, I mean, it here treats `n` like a variable. I think it's functional, but it's not. That makes me confused.

Comment: n is not a variable,  `Twice(n)` in that context is a pattern and you are extracting `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it means `Twice(n)` --> `Twice.unapply(n)` --> `Twice.unapply(42)`

No, `Twice(n)` is a pattern (here; it can also be used as an expression, but with a different meaning), and `Twice.unapply(n)` is an expression. And it's an expression which makes no sense here, because you don't have a value for `n` yet! `Twice.unapply(x)` is called instead.

`x match { case Twice(n) => ...expression_using_n; ...other cases }` is basically the same as

```
Twice.unapply(x) match { 
  case Some(n) => ...expression_using_n
  case None => x match { ...other cases }
}
```

Or to remove circularity, since `Some` itself is an extractor object:

```
val unapplied = Twice.unapply(x)
if (unapplied.isDefined) {
  val n = unapplied.get
  ...expression_using_n
} else 
  x match { ...other cases }
```